# Can Cassandra handle a table containing 20 billion individual pieces of information?

Tags: cassandra

I understand that Cassandra is massively scalable, but it currently has a [limitation](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/CassandraLimitations) 
for storing 2 billion individual pieces of information.

Now, say I want to store information in a table and I have 20 billion data points.  An example might be storing multiple devices (desktop PC, mobile devices, etc.) per user, where there are over 7 billion individuals (possible users) on the planet.  With multiple devices per person, it is conceivable that the data set could reach 20+ billion records.

1. Can Cassandra handle this scenario? If possible, then how?
2. If not, how can this scenario be handled?

Comment: World population is only 7 billion. And how would you enter the 20 billion records? Your requirement makes no sense.

Comment: @Raedwald Edit made.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Yes, Cassandra can store 20 billion or more individual pieces of data.

> The maximum number of cells (rows x columns) in a single partition is 2 billion.

This is the [limitation](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/CassandraLimitations) you alluded to, but it is more specific than your interpretation. Specifically that limit is for a *single partition*.  Were you to insert the maximum *2 x 10<sup>9</sup>* records into a partition, it would require a minimum of 10 separate partitions to, collectively, store the hypothetical 20B records.  Creating 10 partitions is easy.

This is the answer to the "how" in the original question: **Cassandra scales beyond this limitation when *you*, the application developer, split the data across *multiple partitions*.**

In fact, a well-designed, healthy Cassandra *cluster* will consist of thousands or millions (or more) individual partitions.  While each partition can theoretically contain a unique set of two billion data points, *in practice* you are unlikely to see partitions grow to be that large, and you *should not* design your schema with the intent to reach that limit.  (After all, it *is a limit* and should be avoided.)

A single *node* (separate machine) in a Cassandra cluster can store multiple partitions, but the data for each partition must be able to reside completely within one node. That node must also perform *sort* operations on the partition when making changes to its data. You can probably imagine that sorting anywhere close to a billion data points will take measurable amounts of time. Instead, **Cassandra intends you to scale "massively" by distributing the work by *distributing the data* across multiple nodes.**  Production clusters can easily consist of dozens, hundreds, or even thousands of individual nodes.

1. Avoid getting anywhere close to the 2B/partition limit by splitting data across many partitions.
2. Each node will be able to hold a finite number of partitions, based on the capacity of its disk.
3. Avoid being limited by disk space by adding more nodes to your cluster, thus distributing the same data across more disks.

Comment: Thumb up for 'In fact, a well-designed, healthy Cassandra cluster will consist of thousands or millions (or more) individual partitions'

Comment: Thanks William for the answer but it seems still confusing as there are more other documents regarding the cassandra limitation and interpretation. So far what I understood-   1. Using partition key we can create any number of partition   2. In each partition(Each row), it can have 2B column values.

Comment: Partition != row.  Columns are stored in rows.  Rows are stored in partitions.  Partitions are stored in nodes.  One or more nodes make up a cluster.  All of those terms are _different things_.  The count of all columns of all rows in _one_ partition must be <= 2 billion.  (Tip: make sure you're reading documents that pertain to _recent versions_ of Cassandra; some of the terminology changed meaning a little bit when they introduced CQL.)

Comment: @William would you check the following link ?<br> [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20512710/cassandra-has-a-limit-of-2-billion-cells-per-partition-but-whats-a-partition/27150516#27150516). Actually a straight forward example would be great to understand and interpret.

Comment: See slide #48 of [this presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/DataStax/understanding-how-cql3-maps-to-cassandras-internal-data-structure)

Comment: For creating a single partition, we will use a unique partition key. Then using different clustering key values, we can have multiple rows under same partition. Now *The count of all columns of all rows in one partition must be <= 2 billion*. Am I correct now ?

Comment: As that's what I said in a previous comment, yes.